# Can the phrase "out of" be used to specify part of the whole?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

> Only one **out of** twenty students in my class passed the test.

I think the usage "out of" in the sentence above I created is correct, but I am unsure if the following usage is correct:

> This sketch shows only the first floor **out of** my house.

I am afraid that using "of " instead of "out of" may cause misunderstandings as my house has only the first floor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*out of* can be used to specify part of the whole and your first sentence is an example of this.
However the second sentence is incorrect as the first floor is the only floor and therefore is not part of the whole, it  is the whole. You also do not need the word *only* for the same reason as it implies that there are other floors. Thus you could say

> This sketch shows the [first] floor plan of my house.

Unless it is essential for some other reason, there is no need to include the word *first* either. Or you could call it a *single story house*

> This sketch shows the floor plan of my single story house.

which tells the reader that there is no other floor in the building.
But note, in either case, the usage is **of** not **out of**

Comment: Could you advise me on whether the following usage is correct?:  "Out of the USA and the U.K, I have only been to the U.K."

Comment: @rama9 I would say that **out** is unnecessary, just say **Of the USA and the UK, I have only been to the UK** or if you must use *out of* then **I've only been to the UK out of the UK and the USA** but that sounds cumbersome and you would expect the context to be more like **I've only been to the UK out of all the countries in Europe** . In other words *out of* is more commonly used to express a choice from multiple items, not just 2 when it's an *either / or* situation.

Answer (score 1):

> This sketch shows only the first floor **out of** my house.

I would say **of** sounds more natural than **out of** because the sentence is about a physical part-whole relation: a floor is a structural part of a house (whether or not there are multiple floors). Thus it is similar to *the windshield **of** my car*.

If you describe the floors more explicitly as a GROUP, then **out of** works: "**Out of** the floors of my house, this sketch only shows the first floor." Just **of** is OK here too. Of course, referring to the plural *floors* of the house implies that there are multiple floors.